# Pause scene before transition and perform transition

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, pause

I'm struggling with pause moment in my game.
I want to make button which perform pause logic and transition me to another scene with save action to sceneManager that holds gameScene.

Everything works fine but I can't make pause all actions my scene has. I read quite a lot of themes but still no luck.

The only think that really pauses any movement on my scene is

```
self.scene.view?.isPaused = true
```

But it pauses my transition as well.

I have spawning enemies, power-ups, shots and background stuff. So if I translate to other scene with this code:

```
transition.pausesOutgoingScene = true
transition.pausesIncomingScene = true
```

I see that objects and actions are not paused as well!

How to get pause logic work?

Comment: Pause is bugged in Sprite Kit,  My apologies, Pause is working as intended as far as apple is concerned (It really is bugged)  What happens is when paused is set, it sets all of its children to the parent paused value.  This causes inconsistency in the nodes and they start running when they should not be.  You need to somehow preserve and reset the pause value for the nodes you want set, it is a really annoying process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added all nodes I want to pause to the same SKNode instance and after that I can just write:

```
someNodeWithSpritesToPause.isPaused = true
physicsWorld.speed = 0
```

This code solves my problem.

Thank you!